# How to update a variable value after passing it to a view

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, render

So i have an array list that i'm displaying in my view (ejs)

```
app.get("/list",(req, res) => {
  const { db } = req.app.locals;
  db.collection("animal")
    .find()
    .toArray(function(err, results) {
         res.render("./list.ejs", { animals: results});
    });
});
```

Now i need to update the value of this variable ! so i need to re-send the value of "animals" to my view again (without calling render and without reloading the page)

And it seems like express views doesn't support realtime modification . 
I even tried to declare the array variable as a public variable but it didn't work . 
Is there a solution for this (besides the socket solution)
THANKS

Comment: Express doesn't support something like two-way binding like AngularJS, if is what you want. I don't see any alternatives for to do so only with express.

Comment: Using sockets or ajax are your choices